# Can't save Image from external API into Database

Tags: plugin-development, uploads, rest-api, api

I am trying to create a plugin that gets data from an external API and stores the data into the database. The data I am receiving, contains Texts and Images. I have to save them separately as in the thumbnail the image doesn't show as it is not saved separated inside the database. The following is my code that I am using.

```
function save_image_as_attachment($image_url, $post_parent) {
    $image_url = esc_url($image_url);
    $image_data = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_safe_remote_get($image_url));
    
    if ($image_data) {
        $file_name = sanitize_file_name(basename($image_url));

        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $upload_path = $upload_dir['path'];

        wp_mkdir_p($upload_path);

        $file_path = $upload_path . '/' . $file_name;

        file_put_contents($file_path, $image_data);

        $attachment = array(
            'guid'           => $upload_dir['url'] . '/' . $file_name,
            'post_mime_type' => 'image/jpeg',
            'post_title'     => $file_name,
            'post_content'   => '',
            'post_status'    => 'inherit',
            'post_parent'    => $post_parent,
        );

        $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file_path, $post_parent);

        if (!is_wp_error($attachment_id)) {
            require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php';
            $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $file_path);
            wp_update_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $attachment_data);

            return $attachment_id;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The following is the error that I am getting.

```
Warning: file_put_contents(E:\xampp\htdocs\myproject/wp-content/uploads/2023/10/safksdfhkh.jpg): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\wp-content\plugins\apiplugin\api_functions.php on line XXX
```

I have tried using the `mkdir($upload_path, 0775);` on if the directory doesn't exist. I have checked that the directory exists and all permissions are proper `(755)`. When uploading the image from the WordPress dashboard, the image is uploaded in the database, but I need to store is by getting it from the api.

Comment: _on line XXX_  What is the line number and what code is on that line?

Comment: @shanebp The code on that line is `file_put_contents($file_path, $image_data);`.

Comment: Then before that line, write those 2 variables to your debug log and see what is in or not in them.

Comment: @shanebp I solved it by adding the following.
```
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
```
But the problem is, the media does not load. Not even in the WordPress Dashboard.

Comment: Was the image uploaded?  Was an entry made in the posts db table?  _iow._ basic debugging to narrow down the issue.